# Radial basis network character recognition

Tags: arrays, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

I want to develop a simple character recognition program by implementing a given neural network kind; a simple command line-type is enough.

The radial basis function neural network was assigned to me and I already studied the weight training, input-to-hidden-to-output procedures but I am still doubtful of in implementing it. My references are [(1)](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~daa/courses/GSAC6017/rbf.pdf) and [(2)](http://www.eee.metu.edu.tr/~halici/courses/543LectureNotes/lecturenotes-pdf/ch9.pdf).

A simple one-dimensional array of a 10 by 10 binary object (that represents a character) is the input. For example, the array below

```
input = array( 
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 )
```

is the representation of the character "A":

```
0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I plan to take the total weight of the input and compare it to the training set as in the saved 1-D arrays of the other characters of the alphabet and the one with the closest is the prediction.

The problem is I tend to understand algorithms better if presented in a CLRS-manner or similar type as opposed to mathematical formula. I find it hard to understand the explanations in those two papers (which I find the easiest to read among others here in the Google search).

Can someone point me to a friendly algorithm for a RBNFF that takes in an array and produces an output of weights? If not, a paper that explains this in Layman's manner would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems more a question for the AI stackexchange site.  http://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't really get "I plan to take the total weight of the input and compare it to the training set as in the saved 1-D arrays of the other characters of the alphabet and the one with the closest is the prediction."

Comment: by CLRS do you mean pseudo-code? matrix multiplications and stuff really tend to be messy in pseudo-code

Comment: is it the prediction or training (or both) you want to have clearer?

Comment: paper #2 basically says: here's the goal function good luck optimizing that.

Comment: I think the ECOG stuff you added is a separate question :)

Comment: Okay thank you! I'll do it now.

Answer (score 1):

### Training

For what I could find there is no "one right way" to train them.

The simplest training I could find was by a composition of two algorithms

1. (Clustering) Taking the left part (input weights and RBFs) of the network and doing unsupervised clustering. There is a few things you can try out hard/soft and the number of clusters/RBFs.
   Each cluster is a representation of a single RBF with the weights connecting to it.
   How you go from having clusters to get rbf and rbf weights depends on what clustering you are using. (I can extend this if it's unclear)
2. (Neural Network) The solving the left out part of the original RBFNN from the last step by using the output from the clustering as input to an ordinary single layer neural network.

Probably easier to find these more primitive algorithms easily explained

### EDIT

found some "pseudo"-code with explanations that might explain it all better (written in C#)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532201.aspx

(Supposedly) working python code

https://github.com/andrewdyates/Radial-Basis-Function-Neural-Network

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this answer. Do you know any neural network algorithm that can replace RBFNN that has a simpler implementation? (except form MLP)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_artificial_neural_networks
has a list but I think they are either harder, MLP, or not applicable (unsupervised). Is convolution network considered a MLP?

Comment: It's the first time I've heard of them and I am interested to know it :D